# Forcing a user to pick the location to save a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page that allows a user to download a zipped file of spreadsheets, the problem I'm having is when the file is downloaded the user can't find the file. The file is on their machine however in the default location that they have set to download the files. My question is, is there any way to force the user to choose a save location for their file. So far I've tried setting the content type to "application/octet-stream" an "application/zip" which prompts the open with box in firefox, but I haven't been able to get a save as dialog. Is there anything I can do to make it more explicit where the file is downloaded. Everything downloads fine, the user just doesn't know how to find it.

Comment: As far as I know, that's only available as a browser setting.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, it might just be best to add a note or something to help the user. From all I've read you're extremely limited as far as file saving goes for security reasons.

Comment: Would a `SaveFileDialog` suit you or am I misunderstanding something?